# How to convert an ASCII value into a character in .NET

Tags: .net, integer, ascii

There are a million posts on here on how to convert a character to its ASCII value.
Well I want the complete opposite.
I have an ASCII value stored as an int and I want to display its ASCII character representation in a string.

i.e. please display the code to convert the int `65` to `A`.

What I have currently is `String::Format("You typed '{0}'", (char)65)`

but this results in `"You typed '65'"` whereas I want it to be `"You typed 'A'"`

I am using C++/CLI but I guess any .NET language would do...

*(edited post-humously to improve the question for future googlers)*

Comment: Er, "posthumous" means post death. I want some of the technology that enabled you to achieve posthumous editing!

Comment: @Jason one of the most important preconditions of posthumous editing is that you have to be dead. However I do not recommend you try to test this out! :D
(of course I meant post-answeredly but that's not a word)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++:

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Console::WriteLine(String::Format("You typed '{0}'", Convert::ToChar(65)));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And we have a winner! Thanks :)

Answer (score 21):

There are several ways, here are some:

```
char c = (char)65;
char c = Convert.ToChar(65);
string s = new string(65, 1);
string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[]{65});
```

Comment: The last two should be appended with `[0]`. That is, for example, `char c = new string(65, 1)[0];`.

Comment: @Jason: Yes, you can do that it you really want it as a char. If he's going to concatenate it with other strings there is no point in creating a string to create a char that is going to be turned into a string again before it can be concatenated.

Answer (score 8):

For ASCII values, you should just be able to cast to char? (C#:)

```
char a = (char)65;
```

or as a string:

```
string a = ((char)65).ToString();
```

Comment: It does not show NUL, SOH for numeric characters from 0 to 9. Got it?

Comment: @ManishDubey it'll work fine; they're just non-printable control codes

Answer (score 3):

```
 Dim str as string    
 str = Convert.ToChar(65).ToString()
 msgbox(str)
```

Answer (score 2):

The complex version, of course, is:

```
public string DecodeAsciiByte(byte b) {
    using(var w = new System.IO.StringWriter()) {
        var bytebuffer = new byte[] { b };
        var charbuffer = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetChars(bytebuffer);
        w.Write(charbuffer);
        return w.ToString();
    }
}
```

Of course, that is before I read the answer using the `Encoding.GetString` method. D'oh.

```
public string DecodeAsciiByte(byte b) {
    return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] { b });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just cast it; couldn't be simpler.

```
// C#
int i = 65;
Console.WriteLine((char)i);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to od this.  If you wanted them to type consecutive digits w/op delimters and spaces, then you could use something like:

```
    string userInput = "123456";
    var digits = str.Select(c => Convert.ToInt32(c.ToString()));
```